# Groovy, STS, and debug info, information, or symbols

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, debug-symbols, debug-information

I'm trying to include the debug information or symbols in my Groovy code so that I can use the Spring Security annotations with SpEL to access an annotated method's arguments by name. For example:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'View')")
public void doSomething(Integer id)
{
   ....
}
```

Everything works fine when I use the STS 'run-test' command, which uses the Groovy RunTest script. By that I mean I can access a method's argument by name. However, whenever I try to use the 'run-app' command, the debug information is not included.

I looked at the RunTest script and the script explicitly calls the Java Compiler with the debug option set to true.

How can I enable debug information for my development and production environments? Do I need to modify the Groovy script to call the Java compiler on the Groovy code or is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Never found an elegant solution to this. Instead I just used filters as the parameters that were being passed to my methods were being extracted from the URL by Grails.